# only getting limited metrics from the kong ingress controller

Tags: prometheus, grafana, amazon-eks, kong-plugin, kong-ingress

I'm currently facing some challenges with my Kong Ingress Controller setup on Kubernetes, and I could use some guidance from the experienced minds here.

Issue: I'm only getting limited metrics from the kong ingress controller like kong_memory_lua,kong_nginx_connections_total,kong_memory_workers_lua_vms_bytes,kong_nginx_requests_total and kong_nginx_timers , I'm not able to fetch metrics like latency_metrics, status_code_metrics, upstream_health_metrics, bandwidth_metrics
[metrics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOZ0e.jpg)
Details:
Kong Version: 3.3
Kubernetes Version: 1.27

Steps Taken:
I tried by adding env in kong deployment file to enable metrics like latency_metrics, status_code_metrics, upstream_health_metrics, bandwidth_metrics
[env in manifest file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xj2H.jpg)

I've gone through the documentation and tried a few solutions, but I'm still stuck. If anyone has experience with Kong Ingress Controller or Ingress-related setups on Kubernetes, I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions you can provide.

Thank you in advance for your help

I'm trying to plot dashboard in grafana using promthuese , but I'm not getting any data in dashboard ,I installed required plugin but stll not getting data in dashboard, but some of the data is loading
[Kong dashbroad (ID 7424)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuKPI.png)

[kubectl describe kongclusterplugin prometheus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PtEg.png)